# Insert a character before and after all letters in a string in Java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I want to insert a `%` character before after every letter in a string, but using StringBuilder to make it fast.

For example, if  a string is 'AA' then it would be '%A%A%'. If it is 'XYZ' then it would be '%X%Y%Z%'

Comment: It looks like you also insert a % character at the start of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String foo = "VWXYZ";
foo = "%" + foo.replaceAll("(.)","$1%");
System.out.println(foo);
```

Output:

> %V%W%X%Y%Z%

You don't need a `StringBuilder`. The compiler will take care of that simple concatenation prior to the regex for you by using one.

**Edit in response to comment below:**

`replaceAll()` uses a [Regular Expression (regex)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

The regex `(.)` says "match any character, and give me a reference to it" `.` is a wildcard for any character, the parenthesis create the backreference. The `$1` in the second argument says "Use backreference #1 from the match".

`replaceAll()` keeps running this expression over the whole string replacing each character with itself followed by a percent sign, building a new String which it then returns to you.

Comment: This answer is a best answer, very good. @Brian Roach please explain more about your answer such as "(.)" or "$1%".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    String test = "ABC";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    builder.append("%");
    for (char achar : test.toCharArray()) {
        builder.append(achar);
        builder.append("%");
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String escape(String s) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    boolean wasLetter = false;
    for (char c: s.toCharArray()) {
        boolean isLetter = Character.isLetter(c);
        if (isLetter && !wasLetter) {
            buf.append('%');
        }
        buf.append(c);
        if (isLetter) {
            buf.append('%');
        }
        wasLetter = isLetter;
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("AAAAAAA");

for(int i = sb.length(); i >= 0; i--)
{
    sb.insert(i, '%');
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you really don't want to use a StringBuilder at all to do this, this is the worst performing approach using a StringBuilder. You're having to move data for every percent you're inserting. See the other answers that are using `append()`

Answer (score 0):

You may see this.

```
    String s="AAAA";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    char[] ch=s.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
    {
        builder.append("%"+ch[i]);
    }
    builder.append("%");
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Output

```
    %A%A%A%A%
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@Brian Roach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302916/brian-roach) to add character to before and after but if you want to add any specific character then do like this

```
String source = "hello good old world";
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
String[] strArr = tagList.split(" ");

for (String str : strArr) {
     char[] stringArray = str.trim().toCharArray();
     stringArray[0] = stringArray[0];
     str = new String(stringArray);
     //here you need to specify your first and last character which you want to set 
     res.append("#"+ str + "$").append(" ");
 }

 System.out.println("Result: " + res.toString().trim());
```

> Output :- #hello$ #good$ #old$ #world$